# How to change a RDS availability zone to a different one within the same region on AWS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, latency

I currently have a EC2 instance working with an MySQL RDS database. They are both in the same region, but in different availability zones. Currently my application is experiencing a bit of lag, and it is my intuition that it is due to this.

How can I change the AZ of my RDS database to speed up my application?

Locally I am running the same application and it is significantly faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application is read heavy, you can add more reader endpoints in other AZs.

If your RDS is single instance and in the different AZ to your EC2 instance, you will need to take a snapshot and create the instance again in order to change the availability zone.

Comment: modified my answer. you can have more reader end points . are you using RDS Aurora or RDS Mysql ?

Comment: I'm using RDS MySQL

Answer (score 9):

To change AZ modify your RDS to multi-az then perform reboot with a failover and modify it back to single-az.

Comment: I just did this with my RDS, made it multi-az, rebooted, then modified it back to single AZ, and it never gave me a choice (that I could see) to select the AZ I wanted. So it appears to be in the same AZ as it was before I modified it.

Comment: This process worked for me. Notes: I started with an RDS subnet group with only two subnets, one in each of two availability zones. AWS defaulted to the wrong AZ when I initially created the RDS instance. I modified it and created a standby instance - which made the RDS instance multi-az - and AWS assigned the other AZ as the secondary availability zone, which is the one I wanted. Reboot with failover swapped the availability zone and secondary availability zone, putting the instance in the correct AZ, and turning off multi-az left the instance there.

Comment: This worked for me. I thought the AZ would change after the reboot with failover,  but the AZ didn't change until I disabled Multi-AZ.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a read replica in the AZ you need, promote it to be the primary and delete the old primary.